# ADF - Loop through a large JSON file in a dataflow

Tags: azure-data-factory

We currently receive some metadata information from a third party supplier in the form of a JSON file.

The JSON file contains definitions of some tables which need to be loaded into SQL via ADF.

The JSON file looks like this, it's a list of tables and their data types

```
"Tables": [
            {
            "name": "account",
            "description": "account",
            "$type": "LocalEntity",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "dataType": "guid",
                    "maxLength": "-1",
                    "name": "Id"
                },
                {
                    "dataType": "string",
                    "maxLength": "250",
                    "name": "name"
                }
                ]
            },
            {
            "name": "customer",
            "description": "account",
            "$type": "LocalEntity",
            "attributes": [
                {
                    "dataType": "guid",
                    "maxLength": "-1",
                    "name": "Id"
                },
                {
                    "dataType": "string",
                    "maxLength": "100",
                    "name": "name"
                }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

What we need to do is to loop through this JSON and via an ADF data flow we create the required tables in the destination database.

We initially designed the Pipeline with a lookup activity that loads the JSON file then pass the output to a foreach loop. This worked really well when we had only a small JSON file but as we started using real data, the JSON file was over the limit of 4MB resulting in the lookup activity throwing an error.

We then tried using a mapping dataflow by loading the JSON as a source, then setting the sink as a cache and outputting this to an output variable which we then loop through but again this works with smaller datasets but as soon as the dataset is large enough it can't parse it to an output.

I am sure this should be easy to do but just can't get my head around it!

Comment: Could you put the json into a table in sql database with Copy Activity.  Then read x number of 'tables' at a time from this new table in a lookup that you foreach over.  Wrap the lookup-for each inside a loop to continue until you process through all the tables.  Basically add another loop around what you have to process batches of tables at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample procedure to loop through large JSON file in a Dataflows.

Create a Linked service and dataset to the json file path.
[image]

Provision the dataset to the source in the dataflows.
[image]
[image]

By the flatten formatter will get the input columns from the source through Unroll by option with required input.
[image]

Create linked service and dataset to the sink path.
[image]
[image]

Attach the data flow work item to the Data Flow activity.
[image]

Will get result as per the expectations in the sql db.